# Can't call bootstrap datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

First in head I add this:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js'></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="datepicker/css/datepicker3.css">
```

after that I create a html:

```
<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="servis">Servis</label>  
  <div class="col-md-8">
<div class="input-append date" id="servis" data-date="2014-05-05" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd">
  <input class="span2 form-control" size="16" type="text" value="">
  <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
</div>    
  </div>
</div>
```

and after that I use datepicker() like this:

```
 $("#servis").datepicker({
            dateFormat: "yyyy-mm-dd",
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
    });
```

I try every combination but I just every time get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

on line:  `$("#servis").datepicker({ ... ...`

Is someone have the same problem? How I can solve that?

Comment: Looks like you might not have `jQuery` added... it's trying to call `.datepicker()` on an undefined object, which in this case looks like `$`

Comment: jQuery is on top of <head> : <title>AgroAgro</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js'></script>

Comment: and jquery also work with some other .ajax code that I have ...

Comment: Do this for me, open your code in `Chrome`, hit `f12` click on the `Console` tag and copy/paste what it says

Comment: it say again: TypeError: undefined is not a function, I try this many times, but whole day I cant solve the problem

Comment: I also try to use jquery-latest but again is the same result ... not work

Comment: try this, `jQuery("#servis").datepicker({ options });`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54291/discussion-between-gmaestro-and-phil).

Comment: as you can see my dateicker is behind modal indow now:http://i.imgur.com/ifFefgI.png